# Alternative to cURL connect-to

Tags: javascript, curl, postman

This endpoint of an API works fine like so:

```
curl -s -G \
  --connect-to "mumbai403::103.150.187.3:" \
  --cacert "ca.rsa.4096.crt" \
  --data-urlencode "pt=mytoken" \
  --data-urlencode "pubkey=mypubkey" \
  "https://mumbai403:1337/addKey"
```

However, if I remove the `connect-to` and directly provide the IP, there's no response:

```
curl -s -G \
    --cacert "ca.rsa.4096.crt" \
    --data-urlencode "pt=mytoken" \
    --data-urlencode "pubkey=mypubkey" \
    "https://103.150.187.3:1337/addKey"
```

Why doesn't it work without `connect-to`? The reason I need to get rid of it is because I'm not sure how to translate that request to make it work in Postman and elsewhere.

Comment: Your approach is correct could you try with -i and -v flags , it' seems to be ssl version issue . In postman it will work fine if you keep header host as mentioned in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--resolve` to get the actual destination IP (which is likely behind a load balancer).

Hmm, but you'd probably then would have to provide the host headers manually.

https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-connections#provide-a-replacement-name

Comment: But this is still curl specific, right? I wonder how would I achieve this in say node or php?

Comment: These just wrap `libcurl`. And HTTP and DNS are also not cURL specific. The issue likely is, that without the proper host-headers the web-server may not be able to dispatch the request to the proper virtual host (that it's the default catch-all vhost is rarely the case). In case you operate this server, check the DNS setup - because it ordinary shouldn't be required, while the DNS can tell what to do.

Comment: You also could add it into `/etc/hosts` (local DNS) on the server running NodeJS or PHP, in case you don't control the zone-file... because the requirement for such a mapping clearly hints for an absent DNS entry. However, to use it with Postman you'd need public DNS (they cannot map, but have to resolve for).